# Why is this text overflowing and how to not make it overflow?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to create a navigation menu bar using bootstrap, but the text inside the menu overflows, can anybody help?

Here is the screenshot of the text overflow:

[Screenshot of the text overflowing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1n7ji.jpg)

What I'm trying to do is to make the text wrap if it's too long instead of overflowing.

And heres the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Overflowing text</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<div class="dropdown">
    <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Button</button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <div class="dropdown-item">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <h6>Category 1:</h6>
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">This text overflows, how to make it not overflow?</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <h6>Category 2:</h6>
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option1</a></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option2</a></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <h6>Category 3:</h6>
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option1</a></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option2</a></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- partial -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is the value of class dropdown-item

Comment: It's a Bootstrap CSS Class. Debsmita Paul answered below on where it is and what caused it to overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class `.dropdown-item` has a default `white-space: nowrap` property to it which is causing the problem.

You can override the property by adding `white-space: normal!important` to the class.

```css
.dropdown-item {
  white-space: normal!important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Overflowing text</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<div class="dropdown">
    <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Button</button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <div class="dropdown-item">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <h6>Category 1:</h6>
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">This text overflows, how to make it not overflow?</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <h6>Category 2:</h6>
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option1</a></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option2</a></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <h6>Category 3:</h6>
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option1</a></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option2</a></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- partial -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Debsmita Paul! This solved the overflow problem. Where do I find the .dropdown-item property? Is it located in the Bootstrap CSS?

Comment: @learningJust Yes, I think it is in bootstrap.css but I'm not sure. I usually override the css by defining my own css.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a **text-wrap** class to text that you want to wrap.

[image: after adding text-wrap]

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I'm trying to accomplish, is it by using (overflow-wrap: break-word)? I've tried using this inside the div but it still didn't work. Sorry I'm new to this.

Comment: not its using **white-space: normal!important;**

Comment: Thank you Mahendra, this is what it needed.

Answer (score 3):

I noticed that you don't have separate CSS code, so I added in-line CSS code here. I am aware that inline CSS isn't the best practice so feel free to add the modifications on a separate style sheet.

This is what I added to your code:

```
 style="white-space: normal; margin: auto;"
```

Here is the full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Overflowing text</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<div class="dropdown">
    <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Button</button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <div class="dropdown-item">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <h6>Category 1:</h6>
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#" style="white-space: normal; margin: auto; margin-left:-20%;">This text overflows, how to make it not overflow?</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <h6>Category 2:</h6>
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option1</a></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option2</a></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <h6>Category 3:</h6>
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option1</a></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option2</a></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- partial -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add some CSS like here

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Overflowing text</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <style>
    .col{
        min-width: fit-content;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<div class="dropdown">
    <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Button</button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <div class="dropdown-item">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <h6>Category 1:</h6>
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">This text overflows, how to make it not overflow?</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <h6>Category 2:</h6>
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option1</a></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option2</a></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <h6>Category 3:</h6>
                    <ul class="list-group">
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option1</a></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option2</a></li>
                        <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#"><input type="checkbox"> Option3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- partial -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.6.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, it doesn't overflow now, but the div's length increases with the text length, is it possible for the div length to be specific and the text to wrap (like go to the next line), instead of going to the right and make the div longer?